# Converting year-month format to year-quarter [excel]

Tags: excel, function

I'd like to convert year-month (2022-Sep) to year-quarter (2022-Q3). I've found a way to do it, I was just wondering if there was an easier method just for my learning in the future.

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(L2;4);"-";IF(OR(RIGHT(L2;3)="Jan";RIGHT(L2;3)="Feb";RIGHT(L2;3)="Mar");"Q1";IF(OR(RIGHT(L2;3)="Apr";RIGHT(L2;3)="May";RIGHT(L2;3)="Jun");"Q2";IF(OR(RIGHT(L2;3)="Jul";RIGHT(L2;3)="Aug";RIGHT(L2;3)="Sep");"Q3";"Q4"))))
```

My year-month data was in L2.

I'd appreciate any advices how to make it easier.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stackoverflow. Simply using `ROUNDUP(MONTH(L2)/3,0)` gives you the quarter number.

Comment: Looks like your dates are stored as text rather than formatted dates - `RIGHT(L2, 3)` would return 805 otherwise (1st Sep 2022 is 44805 days after 1st Jan 1900).  `DATEVALUE("01-" & RIGHT(L2,3) & "-" & LEFT(L2,4))` will turn it into a date and then use @Helio suggestion:  `=ROUNDUP(MONTH(DATEVALUE("01-" & RIGHT(L2,3) & "-" & LEFT(L2,4)))/3,0)`

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick replies. Unfortunately neither of these methods works as returns #Value error (I think because my default setting for date is hungarian and the format given is english (Szept would be the standard format and Sep is provided in the data)).